# Excel VBA IF Statement -Statement not execution properly

Tags: vba, excel

I need a code like if There is "Good PG" in column BM following condition should run

```
    `Dim val As Range
     Dim myrange As range
     Dim ws_zfi As Worksheet
     Set ws_zfi = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ZFIGLABACUS")

         lastrow_d = ws_zfi.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
              set myrange = ws_zfi.Range("BM3:BM" & lastrow_d)
              For Each val In myrange
       For Each val In myrange
   If val.Value = "Good PG" Then
    ws_zfi.Range("BO3:BO" & lastrow_d).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-23],'ABACUS BU VALIDATION'!C5:C6,2,0)"
         Else
         If val.Value = "To check" Then
         ws_zfi.Range("BO3:BO" & lastrow_d).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[2],'ABACUS BU VALIDATION'!C3:C6,4,0)"
       End If
       End If

        Next val
```

But after running code if there is "No Good PG" then also only one condition is running, If it is not a "Good PG" second condition should run but for all the rows in column BM only first condition is running. 
I am not getting where I got wrong.

Comment: Did you meant `Dim myrange As Range` - assuming `ws_zfi` is a Worksheet object. Where is this `i` come from?

Comment: I updated my codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues in code:

- `Dim myrange As String` should be `Dim myrange As Range`
- `myrange = ws_zfi.Range("BM3:BM100000")` should be `Set myrange = ws_zfi.Range("BM3:BM100000")`

Also, probably

- `ws_zfi.Range("BO3:BO").FormulaR1C1` should be `ws_zfi.Range("BO3:BO" & lastrow_d).FormulaR1C1`
- `myrange = ws_zfi.Range("BM3:BM100000")` should be `myrange = ws_zfi.Range("BM3:BM" & lastrow_d)`

Comment: after changing all the fields to correct then also first condition is running

Comment: @nikhilnik - Can you aad your current code in question so that I can have a look.

Comment: @nikhilnik - Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45912461/edit) and edit the question by adding new code as edit at the bottom of already existing code.

Comment: @nikhilnik - Add `Set` before `myrange = ws_zfi.Range("BM3:BM" & lastrow_d)`.

Comment: @nikhilnik - Code is executing as desired after adding `Set`. Note that as you are using `If val.Value = "Good PG" Then`, it will be case sensitive i.e. `Good PG` and `good PG` are different.

Comment: code is running fine but if there is "To Check ", Instead of "Good PG", the same first condition is only execution but if there is "To Check", second condition should run

Comment: @nikhilnik - Can you share your sample data, code is running fine for me, executing else condition for "To Check".

Comment: @nikhilnik - As I said before, this code works for me (but this time you have `For Each val In myrange` twice). I suggest you to debug your code and check the value of `val.Value`.

Comment: @nikhilnik - Or else share you workbook so that I can work on it.

Comment: @nikhilnik - You can not upload file on Stackoverflow, you'll have to uploadfile on any public sharing online site.

Comment: @nikhilnik - Which column are you are checking condition for, is it `PG Validation` (`Column BM`)?

Comment: Yes for the column BM

Comment: @nikhilnik - For "To check" in Row 19 code is executing else condition. What is the problem?

Comment: in that column if there is any To Check , this formula should run :ws_zfi.Range("BO3:BO" & lastrow_d).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[2],'ABACUS BU VALIDATION'!C3:C6,4,0)"

Comment: but problem in my file is if there is Good PG or To Check only one formula will running if it is "Good PG" this formula should run : ws_zfi.Range("BO3:BO" & lastrow_d).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-23],'ABACUS BU VALIDATION'!C5:C6,2,0)", if it is "To check" this formula should run: ws_zfi.Range("BO3:BO" & lastrow_d).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[2],'ABACUS BU VALIDATION'!C3:C6,4,0)"

Comment: @nikhilnik - Its doing that. I guess problem is in your formula line. Instead of `ws_zfi.Range("BO3:BO" & lastrow_d).FormulaR1C1` try `ws_zfi.Range("BO" & val.Row).FormulaR1C1`.

Comment: That's it @Mrig the code is working fine now thanks a lots man really you are awesome man....!

Answer (score 0):

The if condition in VBA is like this:

```
if(Condition(s)) then
'Code Block Here
End If
```